# R : Which method should I choose for correlation analysis of between two dichotomous variables? and How to?

Tags: r, correlation

data example : variable a{1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0}
               variable b{0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1}

can I use spearman method for this analysis?

Comment: Correlations are used for numeric values, you variables are binary, have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phi_coefficient.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can apply both Spearman's and Pearson's correlations on the data. I went on and run both in Python using your data:

```
from scipy.stats.stats import pearsonr
from scipy.stats import spearmanr

a = [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
b = [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]

print("PEARSON'S: ", pearsonr(a, b))
print("SPEARMAN'S: ", spearmanr(a, b))
```

The results were:

```
PEARSON'S:  (-1.0, 0.0)
SPEARMAN'S:  SpearmanrResult(correlation=-0.9999999999999998, pvalue=2.7369110631344156e-47)
```

Comment: thx for your comment, but I'm afraid that it wouldn't be proper for binary variables. What I'm required now I think is advice of statistics

Comment: In that case, @user2974951 correctly states that you should take a look at "Phi Coefficient".

Comment: Thx again! do you know which package support a phi coeffiecient function? phi() just takes a square matrix. But I should deal with 2 by 1000 matrix.

Comment: You can use [Matthews Correlation Coefficient](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.matthews_corrcoef.html) available in sklearn in python.